# Add Heap Analytics code to HTML

Tags: templating, analytics

I'm trying to add Heap Analytics as a tracking tool to my Craft site. From Heap's installation docs, I need to add this code snippet before the closing  tag. I'm pretty new to using Craft, can someone please explain how to go about doing this?

Code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.heap=window.heap||[],heap.load=function(e,t){window.heap.appid=e,window.heap.config=t=t||{};var r=t.forceSSL||"https:"===document.location.protocol,a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript",a.async=!0,a.src=(r?"https:":"http:")+"//cdn.heapanalytics.com/js/heap-"+e+".js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(a,n);for(var o=function(e){return function(){heap.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}},p=["addEventProperties","addUserProperties","clearEventProperties","identify","removeEventProperty","setEventProperties","track","unsetEventProperty"],c=0;c<p.length;c++)heap[p[c]]=o(p[c])};
    heap.load("YOUR_APP_ID");
</script>
```

Heap installation instructions: https://docs.heapanalytics.com/docs/installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the HTML that Craft uses to render your site lives in your `craft/templates` folder.

In one of the files in that folder, you're presumably defining your `<head></head>` tags.

You'd want to find where that is and insert your JavaScript analytics tracking code before the closing head as per the Head Analytics installation docs.

Probably worth a read through the [Craft does](https://craftcms.com/docs/introduction) to familiarize yourself with Craft concepts as well.